# Writing closures without anything before it

Tags: javascript, closures

What does it mean in JavaScript and when I should use it? (sorry for question title, could not think of better :) )

```
{
   var something = 'test';
   // etc..
}
```

Comment: javascript as of ecma 5 does not support block level scoping, so I don't think it has any special meaning. It just creates a variable `something` in parent function scope / global scope

Comment: I don't see the point; JS has function scope, not block, so I don't think there's any difference.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I have tried in strict mode and it's not syntax error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means nothing. `{ }` groups statements together, nothing more, nothing less. It does not affect scope or create a closure or anything else. It's typically used like so:

```
if (true)
    foo();  // one statement

if (true) { // one group of statements
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

Without `if` or similar constructs it still groups statements, just without much effect.

With one exception: Javascript "1.7" defines [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which declares variables in a *block scope*. I.e. the scope of variables declared with `var` is affected by `function () { }` declarations, the scope of variables declared with `let` by simple `{ }` blocks. This is not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is a scope for your variables, in Javascript this is done be defining a function (closure) and immediately calling it.

```
(function () {
    var something = 'test';
})();
// something is out of scope here
```

Comment: I think OP means that there is no `(function() ` before it.

Comment: That does not answer my question but it may be useful for people +1

Comment: @Blender The question isn't very clear (to me). Also, deceze provides good explanation.